# Powershell scripts to send multiple attachements as HTML format

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I have prepared the below scripts to send multiple files as HTML format (not as attachments). But it is adding the company disclaimer within the table of 1st report while sending email.

[No issue with 2nd report].

############ START ############

$report = "C:\Reports\ADReport16.htm"
$report1 = "C:\Reports\ADReport26.htm"

$BodyReport1 = Get-Content "$report" -Raw
$BodyReport2 = Get-Content "$report1" -Raw

$BodyReport1 += $BodyReport2

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer '10.10.10.10' -From 'AD.REPORT@microsoft.com' -To 'xxx.zzz@cisco.net' -Subject "Active Directory Health Report" -Body $BodyReport1 -BodyAsHtml

############ END ############

Comment: Mime is just data that goes into body of message.  Each Mime Attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true  The mime doesn't have to be HTML.  You just need to specify the content type for each MIME attachment.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to make this work by setting `IsBodyHtml` to `$true` Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$report = "Report1.html"
$report1 = "Report2.html"
$BodyReport1 = Get-Content "$report" -Raw 
$BodyReport2 = Get-Content "$report1" -Raw
$BodyReport1 += $BodyReport2

$emailPassword = "<PASSWORD>"
$emailCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("<EMAIL>", $emailPassword)

$smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Port = 587
$smtp.EnableSSl = $true
$smtp.Credentials = $emailCredential

$messageObject = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$messageObject.IsBodyHtml = $true
$messageObject.From = "<FROM>"
$messageObject.To.add("<TO>")

$msg.subject = "<SAMPLE_SUBJECT>"
$msg.body = $BodyReport1

$smtp.Send($msg)
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]